# 'Link error: already defined' when using COM interface

Tags: c++, com, linker

I'm writing a Win32 C++ Console application in VS2013 that uses a COM DLL library. I've added the files:

- COMObject_i.c
- COMObject_i.h

to my project.

Initially I started working in one file with code that looks like this:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "COMObject_i.h"
#include "COMObject_i.c"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Setup and use COM object interface...
}
```

This code runs fine, I'm able to construct the COM object interface and call methods on it.
However now that I'm moving forward I want to move the COM object interface setup to a different class. When trying to do this I get code like this:

**COMObjectWrapper.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "COMObject_i.h"
#include "COMObject_i.c"

class COMObjectWrapper
{
     // Class declaration
}
```

**COMObjectWrapper.cpp**

```
#include "COMObjectWrapper.h"

// Class method definitions
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "COMObjectWrapper.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Use COM object wrapper
}
```

This will not compile and gives me several linker errors that look like:

```
error LNK2005: _CLSID_COMObjectInterface already defined in COMObjectWrapper.obj
error LNK2005: _IID_ICOMObjectInterface already defined in COMObjectWrapper.obj
error LNK2005: _LIBID_ICOMObjectLib already defined in COMObjectWrapper.obj
```

I've tried moving the #include in the Main.cpp to a Main.h and that did not help. I've tried looking inside the COMObject_i files and I found the various things that are being defined more than once but as the files are auto-generated I'm not sure how to fix the problem?

Comment: Only call one include, this include COMObject_i.h,  or include "COMObject_i.c". Anyway, why do you include a c file?

Comment: @JTejedor If I only include the .h it will not compile, complaining that various definitions are missing. The same happens if I only include the .c

Comment: You really include twice the file "COMObject_i.h" because inside  "COMObject_i.c", I suppose you include the header file inside"COMObject_i.c" ...So you are duplicating the header definitions of "COMObject_i.h" ....so several definitions such as _CLSID_COMObjectInterface  are already defined. Just, include 1 file of both, the header file or source file.

Comment: I'm afraid not, looking inside the pregenerated .c file shows that it does not include the .h file at all and in fact creates more definitions, lines like: "MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(CLSID, CLSID_COMObjectInterface, 0x3A....) can be seen inside it. The linker is unhappy because it thinks that it has two copies of the very strange but necessary .c file...

Comment: This: `#include "COMObject_i.c"` does not belong in your wrapper header. It contains interface and class id definitions (not just declarations), and should be in **one** translation unit only. Either move it to the wrapper.cpp file, some other .cpp file, or add it to the source file list with pch for that file disabled.

Comment: @WhozCraig right, that makes sense. How do ensure that it is in only one translation unit? Alternatively how do you add it to the source file list in VS2013?

Comment: You can add it to one TU by just taking what you have and moving it to `COMObjectWrapper.cpp`, for example. It isn't uncommon to just move it to `stdafx.cpp` for MS-pch stock setups. For your setup, moving it to COMObjectWrapper.cpp that is probably the easiest. Adding it as a separate TU that depends on the IDL file compilation gets more complicated still. you have to turn off PCH for that specific .c file. In the end, I think you're easiest bet is just moving that one `#include` to your .cpp file. (And fwiw, I prefer `__uuidof` anyway).

Comment: If you have a type library (either a `tlb` file or embedded in the COM dll) you can just `#import` it instead of worrying about using the wrapper files directly. [#import Directive (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do:

```
#include "COMObject_i.c"
```

Instead, add `COMObject_i.c` as a file to your project.

`.c` or `.cpp` files should be compiled separately, not `#include` d.  Especially, a C file should not be included in a C++ file!

It will probably "work" in this case , to include it just from `main.cpp`, but that is poor style.

Comment: This works perfectly, can't believe I didn't just think to do this before I made this question...